# AJAX only updates a single django model instance

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I have a django project that shows a list of "issue" objects, and each issue object has a boolean field called "fixed". I want the user to be able to press a button that will change "fixed" using ajax, but the button only changes one of the issue objects rather than whatever "issue" that button belongs to, here's a gif of my
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqxhy.gif)

Here is my html:

```
{% for issue in projects.issues.all %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ issue.author.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2">{{ issue.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ issue.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'issue-detail' issue.id %}">{{ issue.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ issue.description }}</p>
            <p>{{ issue.severity }}</p>
            {% if projects.author == user %}
              
              <span id="fixed_bool">{{ issue.fixed }}</span>
              
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="fix-button" value = "{{ issue.id }}">Fix</button>

            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#fix-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "fix_issue" %}',
      data: {
        issueid: $('#fix-button').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("fixed_bool").innerHTML = json['result']
        console.log(json)
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

      }
    });
  })
```

my url

```
path('fix/', views.FixView, name='fix_issue'),
```

and my views

```
def FixView(request):
if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    result = ''
    id = int(request.POST.get('issueid'))
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=id)
    if issue.fixed == False:
        issue.fixed = True
        result = str(issue.fixed)
        issue.save()
    else:
        issue.fixed = False
        result = str(issue.fixed)
        issue.save()

    return JsonResponse({'result': result, })
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute in HTML must be unique.

But every button has the same id: `id="fix-button"`.

Therefore, in your JS code, this—`$('#fix-button').val()`—returns always the first button's value.

To fix this, either create unique ids for each button, or use classes:

```html
<button class="fix-button">...</button>
```

And in your JS code, select the buttons by class name:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fix-button', function (e) {
    ...
    issueid: $(this).val(),
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and for some reason only the first issue is being changed still. I tried printing what the issueid is when each button is pressed, and the id's correspond to each unique issue, so it is indeed getting each unique issue but it still only changes the first one for some reason

Comment: Nevermind, using classes worked, I just wasn't updating the correct label with the line `document.getElementById("fixed_bool").innerHTML = json['result']`, for this I used unique ID's and it worked.